# copy an element as HTML to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard, markup

I've managed to write some jQuery to find an element and copy it's html to the clipboard (ie only).

The problem is that when I paste this into a rich text box area in sharepoint it pastes the HTML as text only.

How do i replicate the user action of highlighting a link on a page and pressing copy. When I do this manually and then paste the clipboard contents the rich text area realises that it is markup and replicates the link as an anchor in the text content.

Comment: Is there definetely no alternative way to do this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know the only programmatic access IE gives to the clipboard allows you to set text data and URL data, but nothing else: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536744(v=VS.85).aspx

This works:

```
window.clipboardData.setData("text", "<div>Testing</div>");
```

...but has the problem you mentioned. Sadly, this doesn't work:

```
window.clipboardData.setData("html", "<div>Testing</div>");
```

A bit surprising, really.

Comment: strangely enough I was just testing whether i could put "html" in there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used to copy/paste a hyperlink  HTML element to the clipboard so that when you paste it the href is hidden and you only see the "prettier" name.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy me!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var copyToClipboard = (function() {
    var _dataString = null;
    $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
    document.addEventListener("copy", function(e){
        if (_dataString !== null) {
            try {
                e.clipboardData.setData("text/html", link);
                e.preventDefault();
            } finally {
                _dataString = null;
            }
        }
    });
    return function(data) {
        _dataString = data;
        document.execCommand("copy");
    };
})();
```